# Wipe data error - Unable to mount '/data'

Tags: recovery-mode, mount

Sorry for my bad English.

I have a "Huawei G610". And i flash wrong rom on it.
Now phone boots up but the "Encryption unsuccessful" page shows. And just has a button "Reset phone".

[image: one]

"TWRP" recovery mod is installed on phone and come up after tapping on Reset phone in prev step.
In TWRP i enter to "Wipe" and select " Wipe data - Factory reset " and i get this error:

[image: two]

```
Unable to mount '/data'
```

I back to TWRP main menu and enter to "Mount"
But "Data" is unselectable !

**Please help me how to fix this problem**

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What TWRP version are you using exactly?

Comment: try to remove recovery.log in /tmp with file manager on twrp...
then try to wipe it again...

Comment: @EscKeyboard How shall that help to make `/data` mount?

Answer (score 1):

If still necessary:

***This will wipe all data on the phone.***

1. Boot into TWRP
2. Select wipe
3. Tap Advanced Wipe
4. Select DATA and press "Repair or Change File System"
5. Press "Change File System"
6. Change the file system to the original file system for your phone.